# Why if (integer) being evaluated as True?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, return

In this piece of code why would line 6 execute with the conditional statement "if f(3):" wouldn't that just be essentially asking "if 3" since f(x) just returns x?

Also why does "not y" return False if y in this case is equal to 3?

```
1   def f(x):
2       return x
3   
4   def g(x, y):
5       if x(y):
6           return not y
7       return y
8   
9   x = 3
10  x = g(f, x)
11  f = g(f, 0)
```

Comment: If you are confused about the way integers behave in a boolean conttext, why don't you write much simpler tests? Start with `print(bool(3))` and grow from there.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm trying to work through Berkeley's CS61A course and I'm supposed to draw an environment diagram for this piece of code

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer to my question, thanks guys. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bool-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for following up with your solution. Can you summarize the findings from the link in your answer? That way, other members of the community can get an idea of what the answer is without clicking through to the link. That also helps in case the link breaks in the future.